# solr: how to convert iso8601date range to daterange for dataimport

Tags: solr

I have a xml file (ead - archival description) contanining a date range '1678/1768' conform iso8601
I would like to introduce this into solr as a daterange [1678 TO 1768]
in my schema.xml I define

```
<fieldType name="dateRange" class="solr.DateRangeField">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
                pattern="(\d+)/(\d+)" replacement="[$1 TO $2]">
    </charFilter>
</fieldType>
```

and

```
  <field name="dateRange" type="dateRange" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

in the datahandler.xml

```
<field column="dateRange" xpath="/ead/archdesc/did/unitdate/@normal"/>
```

when I try to index the system index it but when I query it with `*.*` I receive no output.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The query to get all documents back is `*:*` - not `*.*`. Date range fields can't have filters attached, so my guess is that you can use an [update request processor to reformat](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) the content before it's seen by Solr.  But even better - you can use a regex transformer [directly in your Data Import Handler specification](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-regextransformer) to get the format you want from what the xpath query selects.

Comment: `regex="(\d+)/(\d+)" replaceWith="[$1 TO $2]"` might be what you need.

Comment: Another point I forgot yesterday; you'll probably need to format it as a proper ISO8601 datestamp to be able to index it as a dateinterval.

Comment: it works: as you suggest I create a regextransformer entity and this solved my problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Date range fields can't have filters attached. You can use [use an update request processor to reformat the content](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) before it's seen by Solr, but even better - you can [use a regex transformer directly in your Data Import Handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-regextransformer) specification to get the format you want from what the xpath query selects:

```
regex="(\d+)/(\d+)" replaceWith="[$1 TO $2]"
```